# Is there a site with the (previous) monthly LEGO Store mini-build instructions?

Tags: instructions, lego-store

We have been going to the LEGO Store off & on for the monthly mini-build, but haven't been able to make it there for quite a few. I've been searching the web for the instructions for the builds we missed, but have come up short. LEGO posts the current models instructions for about a week and takes them down. Is there a site where we can find the instructions for the previous mini-build models?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A list of previous monthly mini models can be found on [Brickset](http://www.brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Promotional&subtheme=Monthly%20Mini%20Model%20Build). The instructions can be found in the notes section under the sidebar on the right for each model.

[image]

Comment: Brickset has moved them to a subtheme of [Promotional -> Monthly Mini Model Build](http://www.brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Promotional&subtheme=Monthly%20Mini%20Model%20Build)

Comment: @GregChabala Thanks, I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 6):

On https://lakea.nl/minimodellen, I managed to collect pdf files for all existing models since 2010. Even the ones Brickset does not mention. :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In the following sites the names of the Mini Builds are in english.

https://legominibuilds.wordpress.com/

https://monthlyminimodelbuild.weebly.com/models-grouped-by-month.html

https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-instructions/promotional/monthly-mini-model-build